# Why? Redeclare things to implement interfaces?! in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, events, .net-2.0, interface, implementation

I work in VB.NET v2

I have an interface **IMyInterface** and this interface implements a method *MyMethod*.

I have an object **MyObjectBase**. This object contains a(the same) method *MyMethod*.

1) If now I do `MyObject Inherits MyObjectBase Implements IMyInterface` ***need I to redefine?*** (shadow, override) `MyMethod` in the `MyObject` class?

2) What now if instead the `MyMethod` method I have an `MyEvent` *event*?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In VB.NET, you need to *manually* associate your interface contract with your implementations. Have a look at the following example:

```
Interface MyInterface
    Sub Foo()
End Interface

Class TestClass
    Implements MyInterface

    Public Sub Test() Implements MyInterface.Foo
        Console.WriteLine("Test")
    End Sub

    Public Sub Foo()
        Console.WriteLine("Foo")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Then have a look at the following code and its output:

```
Dim x As New TestClass()
x.Foo()                           ' Output: Foo '
Dim y As MyInterface = x
y.Foo()                           ' Output: Test '
```

This has the advantage that implementing an interface *does not restrict you in naming your function as you want to*. The disadvantage is that you have to explicitly associate your class methods with your interface declarations using the `Implements` keyword.

---

So much about an explanation. Now let me get to your problem: Since you cannot make `Button` implement IVisibleChanged, you can do something like that:

```
Private Event MyVisibleChanged() Implements IVisibleChanged.VisibleChanged

Private Sub RethrowVisibleChanged() Handles MyBase.VisibleChanged
    RaiseEvent MyVisibleChanged()
End Sub
```

`MyBase` is a VB.NET keyword referring to the superclass. Likewise, in the case of `MyMethod`, you can do

```
Private Sub MyInterfaceMethod() Implements IMyInterface.Method
    MyBase.Method()
End Sub
```

This might seem like unnecessary extra work, but in a way, it makes sense: `Button.VisibleChanged` and `IVisibleChanged.VisibleChanged` might be events with two completely different semantics, who just happen to have the same name (after all `Button` *does not* implement `IVisibleChanged`). With your code, you explicitly create a connection between those two.

Comment: A further advantage is that the same function can implement multiple elements, possibly from different interfaces.

Comment: Thanks. Now, if I have an declared *Event* in a Interface and the same event in the base class. Can you give me an example of this? Thanks!

Comment: "you cannot make Button implement IVisibleChanged"... first of all, I can't agree it. Secondly, imagine the situation :__________________________________________________________________________________
**AddHandler CType(myObject, IVisibleChanged).VisibleChanged, RunMe**; 
The RunMe function will never be called.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you implement your child class that you have to redefine it. I believe if you just inherit from the base case, which is implemented anyway, you won't have to if you don't need it.

Comment: I don't understand... In C# I am not forced to do it.    An interface garantees that a method is implemented. Now, if I already have this method implemented in the base class, what is the compiler problem?

Comment: ... and if you do need to modify the implementation of MyMethod, you could have a protected overrideable method in the base class, so that you can modify the implementation without needing to reimplement the interface. Probably a cleaner way?

Comment: @serhio: the compiler problem is that VB only uses explicit interface implementation - i.e. you have to write Implements MyMethod. The C# compiler automatically matches a method to an interface elements if the method has the same name. It's one of the differences between VB and C#.

Comment: Well... I don't need to modify any methods. I like to keep this method as is. In my concrete case I have a *MyButton* inherits Button and a interface **IVisibleChanged** with a event **VisibleChanged**. the Button class have already the VisibleChanged event and I dont know what to do now.

Comment: If it were a sub you could just implement it with a different name: `Private Sub WhateverNameYouLike Implements IVisibleChanged.VisibleChanged` I don't know about events though. Anyone else?

Comment: It's quite similar for events: `Private Event MyVisibleChanged() Implements IVisibleChanged.VisibleChanged`. For details, see my answer. :-)

Comment: I think you still miss his point, guys. He inherited a member named `Foo` from a base class of his derived class. He wants to use _that inherited member_ as an implementation of similarly-named member `Foo` of an interface implemented by his derived class.

Comment: @Pavel: I do understand that. And the answer is: That's not possible. You have to use a workaround, and the easiest workaround is to create a *new* member `TempFoo`, associate that member with `Foo` (interface), and have that new member invoke `Foo` (base class).